# Persisting dynamically added jQuery tabs using cookies

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic, cookies, tabs

I am trying to figure out the best way to persist the state of (static and dynamic) jQuery tabs in my web page. When the web page loads, there'll be one tab by default. The user has option to add/remove tabs. I know we can persist the state of static tabs if we enable cookie option while initializing the tabs.

The question is: "How to persist the state of dynamically added jQuery tabs?".

One option I am considering right now is to store/update the contents of the dynamic tab in a cookie when it is added (and upon content change) and retrieve the cookie to recreate the tab when the page is refreshed.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? Perhaps some standard/built-in functionality or a plugin in jQuery?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the context of when you need this data?  Only while they are on the specific page, while they are logged in, or anytime they are logged in?

Comment: This page is an aspx (ASP.NET) page and is access controlled. So yes, I need to process this on this page when the user is logged in and for that session only. I don't want to persist that data when the session ends (either by closing the browser or by logging out, in which case I'll delete the cookie via code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be broken down into two concepts; how/where is the session id (for lack of a better term) stored and where is the data stored.

You could just use [ASP.Net Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and be done fairly quickly.

You could create you own unique ID and persist the data in a database/xml on the server side and retrieving the data via Ajax when needed.

You could store this information in a [cookies](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

You could store this information in [Local Storage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/).

Be aware each has there own security issues, cookies are typically not secure, so if the user can rename something or put user identifiable data in, cookies are typically frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you Erik for the suggestions. Although the page doesn't contain any sensitive data, I must agree with you that using cookies is not a viable option.